# unintended round up double variable c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

The problem in the principal it is always round up 0.x and the answer is wrong

I'm using code:blocks mingw

please look at this image on transaction 2 it's 99855.7-145.022 but the answer is already rounded up

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x,amort,principalminus,interest,amortbal,theo,adv,advtemp,paid,mri;
    double principal;
    char con;
    adv=0;
    cout<<"CMP Calculator "<<endl;
    cout<<"Base Principal:";
    cin>>principal;
    cout<<"MRI:";
    cin>>mri;
    cout<<"Monthly Amortization:";
    cin>>amort;
    do
    {
      x++;
      interest = (principal*0.06)/12;
      cout<<"Number of transaction:"<<x<<endl;
      cout<<"Amortization amount paid:";
      cin>>paid;
      if(paid>=685.3)
      {
        principalminus = amort - (interest+mri);
        advtemp = paid-amort;
      }
      principal=principal-principalminus;
      adv=adv+advtemp;
      cout<<"Interest:"<<interest<<endl;
      cout<<"Principal Paid:"<<principalminus<<endl;
      cout<<"Advance:"<<adv<<endl;
      cout<<"Total Principal:"<<principal<<endl;

      cout<<"Do you want to continue?:[Y/N]";
      cin>>con;
      cout<<endl<<endl;
    }
    while(con=='Y'||con=='y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions asking why a large chunk of code does not work is off-topic for Stack Overflow and will be closed. Posting images rather than text is also disallowed. Please try running your code through a debugger. You should identify the problematic portion of the code and see if you can solve the error by searching on the Internet. If not, extract the problematic code and make a [mre] (which can be fed directly to a compiler and demonstrate the problem) to demonstrate it. Make sure to tackle one specific issue and post the minimal code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: the problem sir is on my double principal; it round up when it should not be

Comment: @RobertHienz what value did you expect ? Out of that *amortbal* and *theo* are useless

Comment: sir it is incomplete I'm testing the principal the value should be 99710.678

Comment: @RobertHienz ah ok, the value of *principal* is the one you expect, is just by default the print round it, just ask for more digits

Comment: If you want exact financial calculations, you shouldn't be using `double`.

Comment: oh I'm new in programming what should I use sir?

Comment: @RobertHienz I put an answer

Comment: @RobertHienz Use integers, or use a fixed-point library.  As a matter of fact, many financial institutions prohibit usage of `double` or floating point in general when it comes to financial calculations.  That fractional inaccuracy could result in a lot of money either being mistakingly wasted, spent, or given out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for the advice I just started learning c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's 99855.7-145.022 but the answer is already rounded up

you just need to print with more digits, for instance do :

```
cout << std::setprecision(15);
```

somewhere before the other print, for that you need

```
#include <iomanip>
```

and you will have

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
CMP Calculator 
Base Principal:100000
MRI:41
Monthly Amortization:685.3
Number of transaction:1
Amortization amount paid:686
Interest:500
Principal Paid:144.3
Advance:0.700000000000045
Total Principal:99855.7
Do you want to continue?:[Y/N]y


Number of transaction:2
Amortization amount paid:686
Interest:499.2785
Principal Paid:145.0215
Advance:1.40000000000009
Total Principal:99710.6785
Do you want to continue?:[Y/N]n
```

The printed value of *Total Principal* is the right one, anyway understand by definition there is a limit to the precision of any floats, and you can see that in the printed values for *Advance*.

If your compiler support `long double` you can use them, also asking to print 20 digits the result will be :

bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out

```
CMP Calculator 
Base Principal:100000
MRI:41
Monthly Amortization:685.3
Number of transaction:1
Amortization amount paid:686
Interest:499.99999999999998149
Principal Paid:144.30000000000001853
Advance:0.7000000000000000111
Total Principal:99855.699999999999982
Do you want to continue?:[Y/N]y


Number of transaction:2
Amortization amount paid:686
Interest:499.27849999999998143
Principal Paid:145.02150000000001856
Advance:1.4000000000000000222
Total Principal:99710.678499999999964
Do you want to continue?:[Y/N]n
```

Note also you missed to initialize *x* with 0, and it can be `int` rather than a `double`

Comment: thank you very cout << std::setprecision(15); works! I just adjusted it to 10 for my desired result

Comment: @RobertHienz fine, happy coding